# Construct any regular polygon (A003401) that has the same area as the sum of $n$ given triangles

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction, pythagorean-triples

*Original question:
Construct any regular geometric shape that has the same area as given triangle?*

---

[A003401](https://oeis.org/A003401)

...and by construct I mean, suggest steps for construction or provide general idea

My idea is application of generalized Pythagora's theorem.
*Euclid Elements Book* VI. $31$,

I know it's possible (and how) to construct such square and [equilateral triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818571/construct-an-equilateral-triangle-with-area-equal-to-a-given-triangle)

*Euclid Elements Book* VI. $18$,
$\Rightarrow$ **Every (regular) polygon can be visualized as multiple triangles**

Comment: If you mean with straightedge and compass, the half circle is impossible because $\pi$ is not constructible.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the question. Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

You can construct any regular polygon with 3 or more sides if you know the area, A, of the triangle you are trying to construct a similar scaled geometric shape from. Using $A$, create a regular polygon with n sides of side length:

$s = \sqrt{\frac{4A\tan(\frac{180}{n})}{n}}$

and with interior angle being:

$a = 180 - \frac{360}{n}$

Comment: interesting formula, but i think it is not constructible with straightedge and compass. I edited the question according to your answer.

Comment: Using a pencil, straight edge, and a compass you technically can because you know side lengths and angles. But if you want to use the original triangle as a basis then yeah this is different

Comment: area A is not given implicitly

Comment: I don't agree with this. For instance, the angle $\frac{360^\circ}7$ is provably impossible to contruct with compass and straightedge.

Comment: This is fair, if you really want me to I can limit this answer to polygons with nonrepeating rational values for angles and sidelengths

Comment: @Gae.S.regular heptagon is not constructible with compass and straightedge but is constructible with a marked ruler and compass. I edited the question